# Double subscriptions on inner flow with kotlin-flow

Tags: kotlin, reactive, flatmap, kotlin-flow

I have the following problem with my code snippet below;

1. When the set of currently connected barcode-scanners changes, a `set` with the currently connected scanners will be emitted by the `scanners: Flow<Set<BarcodeScanner>>` flow.
2. If I have connected a single scanner, called A, and I scan a barcode this works fine and on the result will be shown on the text-view.
3. If I connect an additional device, and then scan with device A again, I will see the scan result 2 times.
4. It looks like that on every change of the Set<> an additional flow subscription is created in the `collect { scanner.scan() }` and the previous flow is still in place.

How can I solve this? I already played the whole day with different operators etc...
I'm using Flow 1.2.2

```kotlin
 uiScope.launch { //CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Main)
             scanners //Flow<Set<BarcodeScanner>> will emit the set of scanner, currently connected scanners, when one connects/disconnects
                .onEach {
                    txtView.text = "Barcode scanners: ${it.size}\n"
                }
                .flatMapMerge { // Flatten to Flow<BarcodeScanner>
                    it.asFlow()
                }
                .onEach { scanner ->
                    txtView.append("${scanner.name()} [${scanner.hashCode()}]\n")
                }
                .collect { scanner ->
                    //if a new Set<BarcodeScanner> is emitted, this Flow<Barcode> returned by scanner.scan() will be subscribed again, without removing the old stream
                    //resulting in multiple results on a single scan.
                    scanner.scan() //returns an Flow<Barcode>
                        .onEach { barcode ->
                            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtViewBarcodes).append("[${scanner.name()}]: ${barcode.value} (${barcode.type.description})\n")
                        }
                        .onCompletion {
                            Timber.i("[${scanner.name()}]: DISCONNECTED") //Never called
                        }
                        .launchIn(scanScope)
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than:

```
.collect { scanner ->
    scanner.scan()
        .onEach { barcode ->
    ...
```

You should use:

```
.flatMapLatest { scanner ->
    scanner.scan()
}
.onEach { barcode ->
...
```

Where the flow is launched in the same UI scope. The problem you have is `launchIn(scanScope)` is creating a completely separate coroutine that the outer coroutine can't cancel when a new set of barcodes is emitted.